# Deleting registry keys - error in MSDN sample

Tags: c++, windows, registry

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724235%28VS.85%29.aspx) MSDN article is supposed to demonstrate how to delete a registry key which has subkeys, but the code is flawed.

The line that says

```
StringCchCopy (lpEnd, MAX_PATH*2, szName);
```

causes an exception, which is due to trying to copy to beyond the buffer of lpEnd. I tried correcting the solution by replacing that line with the following

```
size_t subKeyLen = lstrlen(lpSubKey);
size_t bufLen = subKeyLen + lstrlen(szName)+1;
LPTSTR buf = new WCHAR[bufLen];
StringCchCopy(buf,bufLen,lpSubKey);
StringCchCopy(buf+subKeyLen,lstrlen(szName)+1,szName);
buf[bufLen-1]='\0';
```

I'm unable to step through the code as the target platform and dev platform are different, but from the logging I've put in the code it looks like it just freezes up, but doesn't throw an exception.

It's frustrating that MSDN articles are wrong...you'd think they would be checked.

Any ideas on how to correct this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's a bug in the sample. Should be `StringCchCopy(lpEnd, MAX_PATH * 2 - (lpEnd - lpSubKey), szName)`. or ever simpler, `*lpEnd = 0; StringCchCat(lpSubKey, MAX_PATH * 2, szName)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind having `Shlwapi.dll` as an additional dependency, it may be easier for you just to use [SHDeleteKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you're only targetting Vista+, [RegDeleteTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379776%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which lives in `Advapi32.dll`) is another alternative.

Comment: Sorry I know I already marked this as solved but I hit a problem. When testing this on a key I made in HKEY_CURRENT_USER it worked fine but when trying to delete a key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE it has no effect.

Comment: @BillWalton you probably don't have permissions to modify anything in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. You need to run with elevated privileges if this is something you absolutely must do.

Comment: Have you got the right privileges for modifying HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE? You need to be running as administrator

Comment: Thanks Mark, so as long as I'm logged in as admininstrator will I have elevated priveleges? One strange thing I noticed is that I get the same return value from SHDeleteKey when I delete the key in HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 1 - which is defined in winerror.h as ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION. Yet it still deletes the key in HKEY_CURRENT_USER and not the ones in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Comment: @BillWalton, being administrator isn't enough. You need to add a manifest to your program to make it request elevation, and Windows will show a UAC dialog every time you start the program.

Comment: I have also found that individual keys have permissions and so one must recurse through each key and set the permissions to allow Administrators to delete, before Administrators can delete, tedious design really.

Answer (score 1):

That change by itself would not be sufficient.  The line of code following it:

```
        if (!RegDelnodeRecurse(hKeyRoot, lpSubKey)) {
            break;
```

would also need to change.  `lpSubKey` would need to be replaced with `buf` since that now contains the full key.

And it probably goes without saying, but be sure to free (delete) `buf` as part of the cleanup.

However, for correctness, it seems as if it would be better just to fix the original line of code by changing it to pass the correct length (which *should* be okay since I believe the maximum key length in the registry is 255):

```
StringCchCopy (lpEnd, MAX_PATH*2 - lstrlen(lpSubKey), szName);
```